# Describing the geometric effect of multiplication by the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why is the geometric effect of multiplication by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ considered a shear in the x-direction with factor 4?

Looking at an example of applying the transformation to a vector $(3, 2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\cdot3+4\cdot2\\0\cdot3+1\cdot2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}11\\2\end{bmatrix}$

How is the x-coordinate expanded by a factor of 4 when it goes from 3 to 11?

Comment: The shear factor in $x$-direction is $4$, but it doesn't mean that $x$ coordinate is multiplied by $4.$ If it were so, it would be a stretching. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Stretching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking at individual vectors, it might be more instructive to examine what this transformation does to the unit square (i.e., to a bunch of vectors all at once):

[image]

It’s not that the $x$-coordinates of every vector are being multiplied by a factor of four. That would be a simple stretch in the $x$-direction, which would turn the unit square into a $4\times1$ rectangle. Indeed, you can see that the difference in $x$-coordinates along any horizontal line is unchanged by the transformation, which wouldn’t be the case if they were being multiplied by four. Instead, the $x$-coordinate is shifted to the right by four times the $y$-coordinate: The farther you are vertically from the $x$-axis, the greater the shift. The net effect is is to shear the square rightwards so that its sides that were vertical now have a slope of $1/4$.